# Google Apps Script fetch stopped working in this url

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, urlfetch

I have a GAS script that used to fetches a JSON from the url ='https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/DailyPricing?props=Ticker,Name,DistributionRateNAV,LastUpdated,Discount,DistributionRatePrice,ReturnOnNAV,CategoryId,CategoryName,IsManagedDistribution,Price,PriceChange,NAV,NAVPublished,Cusip/&_=1685790508696'

It was working fine, but suddenly 3 days ago fetching the url works until timeout and doesn´t return any data.

Fetch doesn't just stop working gettin the json, it doesn't work on the main url either (https://www.cefconnect.com/closed-end-funds-daily-pricing).

I can't find a solution to this issue and I would be very grateful for your help.

The code below refers...

```
var url ='https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/DailyPricing?props=Ticker,Name,DistributionRateNAV,LastUpdated,Discount,DistributionRatePrice,ReturnOnNAV,CategoryId,CategoryName,IsManagedDistribution,Price,PriceChange,NAV,NAVPublished,Cusip/&_=1685790508696'

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}); //here is the problem

var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
```

The script works with other urls that I scrape and it is only with this one that I have started having problems.

Comment: Some sites perform an http request after the main page has loaded. UrlFetchApp cannot retrieve that data.